# Is it clear what seks- means?

Tags: word-choice

In English, the word sex has two meanings. One is about something you are (gender, male/female etc.) and the other is something you do, which I find difficult to describe in few words, but I am certain you understand what I'm aiming for.

I have seen options. Some people say *genro* for *gender*. Is it acceptable only for gramatical genders or for people as well? *Seksumi* clearly means *to have sex*.

What makes me confused are words like *seksa*, *seksalloga* and *samseksema*. They don't make sense to me since I thought *sekso* was a tranlsation of gender, and hence had to do with identity, not sexuality.

Which out of the two meanings I mentioned in the beginning does *seks-* have?

Answer (score 6):

According to PIV (vortaro.net) - *genro* is for grammatical gender. Everything else is *sekso*, *seksumi* and so on. My thought is that people who use *genro* to talk about whether a person is male or female are carrying in prejudices or habits from their national language experiences.

What you are calling "two different meanings" are really just different aspects of a continuous patch of semantic territory. Sex has to do with male and female and how those things relate to reproduction. This is why we can classify a person by **sex** (male or female) or talk about **sex** acts, describe someone as **sex**ually attractive, or homo**sex**ual.

This same semantic territory is covered by the Esperanto root *seks-*. You mentioned *seksumi* (and therefore *seksumado*), and the other words (*seksa, seksalloga, samseksema) are all valid words.

Note on *seksa*: without context, it's not clear what you were told it means. PIV defines it as either

1. Relating to the sexes

   - seksaj karakteroj primaraj, sekundaraj
   - la seksa membro<sup>Z</sup> (peniso)
   - seksa amo<sup>Z</sup> .
2. Relating to the joining of the sexes.

   - la seksaj bezonoj
   - la seksa vivo
   - seksa malsano.

Comment: Great, you answered the question about genro. But what about sekso? Maybe I was unclear in my question: I mainly wanted to know which out of the two English uses of "sex" the root seks- corresponds to.

Comment: I thought about being more explicit, but looking at the definitions and example sentences in PIV, it seemed to me that the overlap with English is pretty clear. You'd already mentioned *seksumi* - so I didn't think I needed to clarify that. I'll add a second paragraph to my answer.

Comment: The meaning of "sekso" in Esperanto is "gender", i.e. whether someone is male or female (or of non-binary gender). The meaning of "sex" as in "to have sex" is expressed with "seksumado" or "amoro".  Even is "samseksema", the meaning of "seks/" is "gender: It means "inclined to the same gender" (the fact that it is sexually inclined rather than inclined in another way is left implicit).

Comment: The use of "seksa" in the sense of "related to the act of sex" on the other hand is fairly common. I think that usage is not completely logical, as the noun "sekso" normally cannot have the meaning of a sex act. It probably entered Esperanto through the influence of other languages.

Answer (score 4):

I have heard people say that sex is biologically based on DNA and that gender is a choice. With that in mind, the root **Seks** refers to a biological classification of male or female. Your DNA can be tested to determine your **seks**.

**Seksa** = Sexual. For example, a sexual disease

**Seksismo** = Sexism (an ideology related to the sex of a person)

**Seksumi** = To have sex - See the root **um** for more details

**Seksumilo** = A tool related to having sex

**Aliseksema** = An inclination towards the other sex. This means being straight.

**Ambaŭseksulo** = Someone who has both sex organs.

**Inseksa** = Female sex

**Samseksa** = Same sex. This does NOT mean gay. Example, I only want to be friends with people of the same sex because otherwise my wife will be jealous.

**Samseksema** = Inclination towards the same sex. This means homosexual.

**Samseksemulo** = A gay person

**Samseksemulino** = A lesbian

**Virseksa** = Male sex

**Virseksulo** = Person of the male sex

**Unuseksa** = Unisex. Some species have only one sex. Humans have 2 sexes, which are male and female.

**Seksmatura** = Sexual maturity (able to bear offspring)

**Seksorgano** = Sex organ

For more info: http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/seks.html#seks.0o