# Why does 'gender' translate to 'sekso'?

Tags: translation, gender

Laŭ mia scio, la Esperanta vorto 'sekso' tradukiĝas al 'sex' en la angla. Sed, ne ŝajnas esti vorto pro 'gender' — Guglo Traduki tradukas 'gender' al 'sekso' kaj Lernu.net ne povas traduki ĝin. Evidente, 'gender' kaj 'sex' ne estas samaj, do kial la tradukoj estas samaj? Ĉu ĉi tiu estas nur problemo, ĉar Esperanto estas malnova kaj ne adaptiĝas kun la tempoj, aŭ ĉu estas bona kialo por ĉi tiu laŭŝajna maleblo ĝuste priskribi la anglajn konceptojn 'sex' kaj 'gender'?

Edito: oni mi demandis al ĝisdatigas la demando kun mia difino de 'sex' kaj 'gender', do: (almenaŭ mia scio), 'sex' estas kiu vi estas allogas al, kaj 'gender' estas kio vi indentigas kiel.

Edito: Ho ve! Mi ne kredeblas mi faris tia grande eraron - 'sex' ne estas kiu vi allogas al; tiu estas 'sexuality'  - 'sex' estas biologaj diferencoj inter homoj.

As far as I know, the Esperanto word 'sekso' translates to 'sex' in English. But, there doesn't seem to be a word for 'gender' — Google Translate translates 'gender' to 'sekso', and Lernu.net can't translate it. Obviously, ‘gender’ and ‘sex’ are not the same, so why are the translations the same? Is this just a problem because Esperanto is old and does not adapt to the times, or is there a good reason for this seeming impossibility to accurately describe the English concepts 'sex' and 'gender'?

Edit: I was asked to update the question with my definition of ‘sex’ and ‘gender’, so: (at least to my knowledge), ‘sex’ is what you’re attracted to, and ‘gender’ is what you identify as.

Edito: Ho ve! I can’t believe I made such a big mistake - ‘sex’ isn’t who you’re attracted to; that is ‘sexuality’ - ‘sex’ is biological differences between people.

Comment: Simila demando: [Is it clear what seks- means?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/q/2173/1576)

Comment: Neniu scias kial Google tradukas tion tiel. Vi trovos en mia respondo tri eblojn tion traduki, laŭ la (konata de mi) nuna uzo. Ĉu iu estas kunvena por vi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Guglo Traduki tradukas 'gender' al 'sekso' kaj Lernu.net ne povas traduki ĝin. Evidente, 'gender' kaj 'sex' ne estas samaj, do kial la tradukoj estas samaj?

You should ask Google about that particular instance. It is just a tool, one additional source of translations.

Since you are here, you might want to take the time to simply ask how to translate `gender` and you will receive many answers, among them `genro` (loaned meaning), `sekso` and `socia sekso`.

If you take that road, do include **your** definition of `gender` because depending on the school this:

> Obviously, ‘gender’ and ‘sex’ are not the same

might not be so obvious as you think. That's the advantage of asking the question properly in this forum, you get to ask for the exact meaning you are looking for, if you spell it out. To *accurately translate* we need your accurate definition.

On a side note, the tool you are using also uses `sex` in the German and French translation of `Gender does not have to be binary` although those in those languages `Gender` and `Genre` are also used. I wouldn't based my research solely on that tool's answer.

Comment: > might not be so obvious as you think.

Laŭ mi scio, la diferencon inter 'gender' kaj 'sex' estas akceptis kiel fakto. Sed, mi konfesas mi devis alkalkulis mia difino, kaj mi ĝisdatigos la demando. (Pardonu por oni gramatika eraroj - mi estas komencanto, kaj mi ankraŭ lernas. Bonvolu sciigas mi de oni eraroj!)

Comment: En ordo. Sekso kaj socia sekso estas ja malsamaj, sed ne ĉiuj samopinias pri tio, ĉu tiu malsamo indigas havi apartajn priskribajn vortojn, kaj pri la vorto kiu devus alpreni la novan signifon.

Comment: > ne ĉiuj samopinias


Mia precipe zorgado ne estas ĉu ĉiuj samopinios pri tiu - laŭ mi, ne havis apartajn priskribajn vortojn ne estas justa al malcisgenro homoj, kaj ankaŭ fakte malprava.

Comment: Ĉu **neniu** el la tri uzataj ebloj bonas por vi? `genro`, `sekso`, `socia sekso`? Ili estas en mia respondo.

Comment: Pardonu, ŝajni 'genro' or 'socia sekso' ambaŭ estas sufiĉe bona. Nedankinde por la helpo kaj pacienco - mi akceptos via respondo.

Answer (score 3):

Depende de kunteksto, la angla vorto "gender" povas aperi en du diferencaj ĉirkaŭaĵoj - kiel difino de gramatika trajto de vortoj kaj kiel difino de sociaj rilatoj. En ambaŭ fojoj ne temas pri fizikaj aŭ biologiaj trajtoj.
Devus konstati ke eĉ en la angla forestas apartaj vortoj por diferencaj nocioj - por socia sekso aŭ genro kaj por gramatika genro. Pro tio aperas eraroj dum iu ajn aŭtomataj tradukoj, kiuj ne analizas aŭ ne havas por analizo plenan kuntekston, kaj kiuj celas tradukon en la lingvoj kie ankaŭ forestas apartaj vortoj por ĉiuj tri sendependaj nocioj - biologia sekso, gramatika genro kaj socia sekso/genro.
Se vi deziras precizecon, do nepre uzu ĝustigitajn multvortajn esprimojn, sed ne solvortajn tradukojn kaj traduku ne vortojn sed nociojn.

Answer (score 2):

La vorto "sekso" estas Fundamenta kaj havas kvin difinojn (vd. [PIV](https://vortaro.net/#sekso_kdc)), el kiuj unu estas arkaika. La kvar restaj temas pri biologio, speciale pri biologio de homoj. La kvina, arkaika difino egalas la nuntempan vorton "genro".

La vorton "genro" oni difinas en la [Naŭa Oficiala Aldono](https://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/decidoj/9oa.html) (9OA):

> **1** Gramatika kategorio (precipe ĉe substantivoj kaj pronomoj, sed ankaŭ ĉe aliaj vortspecoj), kiu almenaŭ historie iel rilatas al la sekso de estaĵoj aŭ al distingo inter uloj kaj aĵoj: vira genro; ina genro; neŭtra genro. **2** Subgrupo de zoologia aŭ botanika familio.

Mi samopinias kun Va Milushnikov. Se temas pri teksto aŭ parolo, en kiu la diferenco gravas, unue difinu viajn terminojn kaj akceptu, ke tiuj povas esti multvortaj.